# Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX or Spreadsheet::ParseExcel doesn't work with .xlsx

Tags: perl

I have a script that works perfectly fine with .xls file but the same file when in xlsx doesn't work with my script.

I use [Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX) to parse the .xlsx file. 
It works fine until getting the row and col range but doesn't work on get_cell or value of the cell.

```
my @name;
my @details = (); 
for my $row(0 ..$row_max) {    
    my $ligand_details = {};

    for my $col (@required_cols) {
        warn Dumper($worksheet); 

        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row,$col);
        warn $cell; 

        my $value =  $cell ? $cell->val :'';

        if($row == 0 ) {                    
            $name[$col] = $value;
        } else {
            $ligand_details->{$name[$col]} = $value; 
        }
    }   
    push @details , $ligand_details if (defined $row); 
}

return \@details;
```

Sorry forgot to add the error message

```
$VAR1 = [
      {},
      {
        '' => ''
      },
      {
        '' => ''
      },
      {
        '' => ''
      },
      {
```

Is there any difference between ParseExcel and ParseXLSX? any suggestions?